# Trouble installing flash player on ubuntu

Tags: flash

When I try to download the flash player version for ubuntu I get a screen asking what program to use to open file. As I am next to computer illiterate I have no clue

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Ubuntu Software Center might be a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about manually downloading and installing flash player. Instead, install package [ubuntu-restricted-extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/). This package contains flash player as well as many other useful multimedia-related things.